# python module not found in sudo mode (ubuntu 20.04)

Tags: bash, 20.04, python, sudo

I am using ubuntu 20.04 to write python programs. I usually install python packages without the `sudo` prefix. But I noticed that if I go into the sudo mode and then try to import a previously installed python package, it would raise `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'xxx'`. But if I exit the sudo mode everything will be alright again.

What could be the reason? Could it be because in sudo mode the import path is not added to the `PATH` variable? But that doesn't seem to be the reason if you check my `PATH` variables below:

Normal user mode:

```
/usr/local/cuda-10.2/bin:/home/myusername/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
```

Root mode:

```
/usr/local/cuda-10.2/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin:
```

Comment: I assume you installed the packages using `pip` (or `pip3`)?

Comment: @danzel Yes I did.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Python doesn't use the `PATH` environment variable. The process of determining where it looks for modules is rather complicated and I won't go into detail here, but in the end, all paths are contained in the `sys.path` variable. Use the following one-liner to print that list:

```sh
python3 -c "import sys; print(sys.path)"
```

(Note that it only contains existing directories.)

In the output, you'll see a folder inside your home folder. That's your user's site-packages directory, a feature described in [PEP 370](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0370/). And that is the directory where `pip3` installs packages by default if you run it with your "normal" user.

If you now switch to the `root` user, python will look for modules in the `root` user's home folder, which is `/root`, so it won't find packages in your "normal" user's site-packages directory.

For development purposes, I would recommend using virtual environments such as `venv`.

Answer (score 1):

My issue (on debian) was that `python` would run python3 and `sudo python` ran python2.

Fixed by running `sudo python3 app.py`

This assumes the modules are installed for root.

Answer (score 0):

Just do `sudo pip install <package-name>`

Answer (score 0):

The solution for me was instead of writing:

`sudo python test.py`

Write:

`sudo /home/dietpi/project/env/bin/python test.py`